# GameObjects will not load after game Restarts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am making a maze game and the keys which are needed to be collected to complete it wont appear again if the game restarts, I get the following error;

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'MazeDirectives' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
```

I am just disabling the MazeKey object, not destroying it, can anyone help? Below is my code;

MazeKey.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MazeKey : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        transform.parent.SendMessage("OnKeyFound", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

MazeDirectives.cs

```
MazeGoal mazeGoal;
MazeKey mazeKey;

void StartDirectives()
    {
        mazeGoal = Instantiate(mazeGoalPrefab, MazeGenerator.instance.mazeGoalPosition, Quaternion.identity) as MazeGoal;
        mazeGoal.transform.SetParent(transform);

        mazeKeyPositions = MazeGenerator.instance.GetRandomFloorPositions(keysToFind);

        for (int i = 0; i < mazeKeyPositions.Count; i++)
        {
            MazeKey mazeKey = Instantiate(mazeKeyPrefab, mazeKeyPositions[i], Quaternion.identity) as MazeKey;
            mazeKey.transform.SetParent(transform);

        }
    }
```

To restart the game I use the code below;

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

MazeGoal.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MazeGoal : MonoBehaviour
{

public Sprite closedGoalSprite;
public Sprite openedGoalSprite;

void Start()
{

    GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = closedGoalSprite;



}

public void OpenGoal()
{
    GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = openedGoalSprite;
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D()
{
    transform.parent.SendMessage("OnGoalReached", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
}
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception? And how do you restart your game?

Comment: Hi ming060, I have updated my question for you, the line of code that throws the exception is `mazeGoal.transform.SetParent(transform);`

Comment: Can you update the code including the declaration of the variable `mazeGoal`? Is it a static variable?

Comment: Sure thing, just edited it for you

Comment: Do you call `StartDirectives` in `Awake` or `Start` or somewhere else?

Comment: I call it in Awake, `void Awake()
    {
        MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives;
    }`

Comment: You might be getting an unintended collision at start-up. In your trigger enter for MazeKey make the first line "Debug.Log(other);". What do you see in the console?

Comment: Hi Absinthe, I get `MazeRunner (UnityEngine.CircleCollider2D)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
MazeKey:OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Maze/MazeKey.cs:8)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explenation

The exception you get is not talking about the `MazeKey` object but rather the `MazeDirectives` component.

Unfortunately you hit the most important information in the comments:

```
private void Awake() 
{ 
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives; 
}
```

so `OnMazeReady` seems to be `static` and not instanced so it will not be destroyed when a new Scene is loaded but keeps intact bloating into the new Scene!

When you call

```
MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady += StartDirectives;
```

you add the call to the `StartDirectives` method of an instance of `MazeDirectives` as listener to that `static` event.

Now when you reload the Scene all `GameObject`s and thereby their instances of components are destroyed

=> so is the instance of `MazeGenerator` ... **BUT** the `static` event `OnMazeReady` is **not** destroyed!

so after the next `Awake` call you now have two listeners

- The one from the "second"/new loaded Scene
- Still the "old" one you added the first time

But since the instance of `MazeDirectives` you added the first listener for is destroyed when the scene is reload and a new instance generated, you get that exception

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'MazeDirectives' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
>   Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

when the method tries to access the `transform` value of the destroyed instance.

---

#### Solution 1a

So you should remove the listener when you destroy the instance

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
     MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady -= StartDirectives;
}
```

---

#### Solution 1b

or overwrite it with only exactly one listener at a time

```
private void Awake() 
{ 
    MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady = StartDirectives; 
}
```

this second aproach obviously is only useful when there is no other instance or class listening to that event. The question is how much sense does it make to use an event than? And I would than anyway remove it if not needed just to be sure

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
     MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady = null;
}
```

---

#### Solution 2

I would prefere this solution.

Don't make `MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady` static at all. Since anyway I see that you are using a Singleton pattern e.g. in

```
 MazeGenerator.instance.mazeGoalPosition
```

you could instead just make `OnMazeReady` Non-static and instead use it the same way:

```
private void Awake()
{
    MazeGenerator.instance.OnMazeReady += startDirectives;
}
```

so it will be destroyed together with that instance of `MazeGenerator`.

---

#### General note

I would **always** remove all listeners I ever added as soon as possible to avoid exactly the issue you have.

You could **additionally** remove it e.g. already inside of `StartDirectives` to make sure the method is executed only once even if the same Scene "accidentely" invoked `OnMazeReady` twice.

Hint: I said *additionally* since it is always save/possible to remove a listener even if it wasn't added before and you should allways leave the one in `OnDestroy` in case the `StartDirectives` is never called before the object is destroyed.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks derHugo! I went with solution 1, and changed the void awake to `MazeGenerator.OnMazeReady = StartDirectives;` , if i could upvote you i would!

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

This answer is wrong at first place. The exception is complaining about accessing the `MazeDirectives`'s `transform`, not `mazeGoal` object.
But the comments below did give some useful info. So I'm keeping this post for references.

For complete solution, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719608/4877424).

---

From the line `mazeGoal.transform.SetParent(transform);` throws the exception:

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'MazeDirectives' has been 
destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
```

From [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html):

> The load of a new Scene destroys all current Scene objects.

The `mazeGoal` has been destroyed when you called the

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
```

to restart the game.

And from [MonoBehaviour.Awake()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html),

> Awake is called only once during the lifetime of the script instance.

Since you only assign the `mazeGoal` variable inside `StartDirectives` function which been called in `Awake`, after loading the same scene again, the actual object of `mazeGoal` has been destroyed.

If you want to reuse the same object when loading a new scene, you can use `DontDestroyOnLoad` to keep the `mazeGoal` object.

Or you can move the `StartDirectives` to `Start` function which will be called every time the gameobject is created and reinitialize your `mazeGoal`.

Comment: Thanks for this ming060! However the MazeGoal reloads fine, its the MazeKeys that will not reload

Comment: Oh, sorry. So the exception is caused by calling `mazeGoal.transform.SetParent(transform);` in `MazeDirectives.cs` and the `transform` is null?

Comment: Yeap I think so!

Comment: Did you `Log` the `transform` one line before the `mazeGoal.transform.SetParent(transform);` to make sure about it?

Comment: `Maze (UnityEngine.Transform)` appears in the log

Comment: Can you get the same result in the first round and second round? If the exception is caused by `mazeGoal.transform.SetParent(transform);` this line, I assume it should be null at second round.

Comment: If i put the log after the line of code, I get `MazeRunner (UnityEngine.CircleCollider2D)` in the log

Comment: What I mean is not logging before and after the line of code. Because you said the `MazeKeys` is not reload properly after restarting the game, so I want to make sure the status of the `MazeKeys` at first and second round of the game.

Comment: Sorry im not quite sure what you mean, Im quite new to Unity!

Comment: When I try to enter the door in the second round, I got this error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
MazeGoal.OnTriggerEnter2D () (at Assets/Scripts/Maze/MazeGoal.cs:27)`

Comment: the issue has nothing to do with `mazeGoal` (since as you said already it is instanced inside of the method) but rather with the `transform` component of the destroyed instance of `MazeDirectives` the method is trying to access (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719608/7111561))